# What are IETF RFCs?

Tags: internet

I've seen these referenced in C++ and Python documentation. Clearly they are some form of governing documents managed by the IETF, but how do they come to be? What level of enforcement does the IETF have on practice standards and the development of new tech?

Answer (score 3):

> Clearly they are some form of governing documents managed by the IETF, but how do they come to be?

The regular process is best documented at the IETF's own website:

- [The IETF Standards Process](https://www.ietf.org/about/standards-process.html)
- [The IETF Process: an Informal Guide](https://www.ietf.org/about/process-docs.html)

The IETF also accepts "independent" submissions:

- [Guidance on Area Director Sponsoring of Documents](https://www.ietf.org/iesg/statement/ad-sponsoring-docs.html)

> What level of enforcement does the IETF have on practice standards and the development of new tech?

AFAIK, none.

Often the market itself enforces compliance with a given standard. In other cases, some other organization which *does* have enforcement powers within some area might list compliance with an IETF RFC among its requirements.

Comment: To drive home the point about independant submissions, you might want to read up on [RFC 1149 - A Standard for the Transmission of IP Datagrams on Avian Carriers](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1149) (IP over Carrier pidgins).

Comment: Oh, I thought there was a WG for April 1st RFCs?

Comment: Maybe there is, not sure